# Android Update Mainactivity List View after popup Dialog updates database

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a listview on my mainactivity that is showing items from a database. I have an add button up in the action bar. When the add button is clicked on a dialog pops up and the user fills out fields for the new item and then they click "add" and it adds the item to the database. The only problem is that the listview on the mainactivity doesn't update to show the new item. I can close the app and reopen it and I see the new item. It just doesn't update immediatly. (Same problem with deleting an item, only the delete happens onLongPress)

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package blah.blah.blah

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InitActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        PlayersDBHelper mDbHelper = new PlayersDBHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_init);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }//End onCreate()

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.init, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                showAddPlayerDialog();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void showAddPlayerDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new addPlayerDialog();
        dialog.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "addPlayerFragment");
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(position == 0) {
                Fragment playersFragment = new PlayersFragment();
                return playersFragment;
            } else if(position == 1){
                Fragment otherFragment= new otherFragment();
                return otherFragment;
            } else {
                Fragment otherFragment2 = new otherFragment2();
                return otherFragment2;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }//End sectionsPagerAdapter()


    public static class PlayersFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public int myFragmentId = 1;
        private ListView mylistview;
        private String[] values;

        public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



        public PlayersFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_players,
                    container, false);
            mylistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);

            registerForContextMenu(mylistview);

            PlayersDBHelper mDbHelper = new PlayersDBHelper(rootView.getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
            // you will actually use after this query.
            String[] projection = {
                PlayerEntry._ID,
                PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID,
                PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,
                PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_POSITION
                };
            String selection = null;            //Null will return all rows for given table
            String[] selectionArgs = null;      //Null should return all data

            // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
            String sortOrder =
                    PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " DESC";


            Cursor c = db.query(
                PlayerEntry.TABLE_NAME,                   // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                sortOrder                                 // The sort order
                );

            values = new String[] {};

            String array[] = new String[c.getCount()];
            int i = 0;

            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                array[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME));
                i++;
                c.moveToNext();
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < array.length ; x++){
                Log.d("Logan", "Entry at:" + x + " is " + array[x]);
                values = push(values, array[x]);
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }

        private static String[] push(String[] array, String push) {
            String[] longer = new String[array.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                longer[i] = array[i];
            longer[array.length] = push;
            return longer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
          if (v.getId()==R.id.myListView) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.setHeaderTitle(values[info.position]);
            String[] menuItems = {"Edit", "Delete"};
            for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
              menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
            }
          }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           PlayersDBHelper mDbHelper = new PlayersDBHelper(getActivity());
           final SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
            String[] menuItems = {"Edit", "Delete"};
            String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
            String listItemName = values[info.position];

            if(menuItemName.equalsIgnoreCase("Edit")) {

            } else {
                //menuItemName === Delete
                // Define 'where' part of query.
                String selection = PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " =? ";

                // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
                String[] selectionArgs = { listItemName };

                // Issue SQL statement.
                db.delete(PlayerEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
        }


    }

    public static class otherFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public otherFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lineup,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class otherFragment2 extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public otherFragment2() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_position,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**addPlayerDialog.java**

```
package blah.blah.blah;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class addPlayerDialog extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Gets the data repository in write mode
       PlayersDBHelper mDbHelper = new PlayersDBHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());
       final SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addplayerdialog, null);

        final ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        builder.setView(view)
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // sign in the user ...
                       EditText fName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
                       Editable firstName = fName.getText();

                       EditText lName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
                       Editable lastName = lName.getText();

                       EditText number = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.playerNumber);
                       int num = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());

                       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.positionSpinner);
                       String position = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                       // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
                       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                       values.put(PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID, num);
                       values.put(PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, firstName + " " + lastName);
                       values.put(PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_POSITION, position);

                       // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
                       long newRowId;
                       newRowId = db.insert(
                               PlayerEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                               null,
                               values);
                       //**** HERE IS WHERE I THINK THE CHANGE NEEDS TO BE! ****
                        ((ArrayAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.positionSpinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.positions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**addPlayerDialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/fName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/lName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/playerNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/playerNumberHint"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/positionSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you inserted the data to the DB but forgot to call `yourListViewAdapter.add` method before calling  `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: What is the best way to get the adapter for the list view? I don't think I am doing it the right way.

Comment: Google about `custom adapter`, this link should serve you well : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html